# What does stream=true do?

Tags: python, python-requests

What does `stream = true` do? I couldn't find anything on the web but I suppose that it have something to do with the memory?

```
requests.get('https://...com', stream=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `stream=True` sets the stage for you to read the response data in chunks as opposed to having the entire response body downloaded in one go upfront.

See https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow for more info.

Comment: broken link - this link does not work anymore

Answer (score 1):

stream = True means "At this point only the response headers have been downloaded and the connection remains open until we access the Response.content"

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow